# Excel 2010 - Macro to Detect Specific Interior Color of a Cell and Produce a Result

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I created an Excel spreadsheet with a command button that calls a macro. The macro produces an new email through Microsoft Outlook that provides a list of data, specifically data from cells ranged A5 through A500 that have an interior color of RGB(255, 255, 204).

However, I'm not getting accurate results. The macro is not exclusively capturing the data from cells of the specified interior color and is giving me data from cells of alternate colors as well. This may be a logic error on my part.

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
Private Sub btnReport_Click()
'Create Email Message
Dim r As Range
Dim m As String
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A5:A500")
m = "Hello,<br><br>Here is some information:<br><br>" & _
    "<table border=""1"" style=""width:98.7%"" align=""left"" ><tr style=""vertical-align:top;""><td style=""width:9.3%"" nowrap>" & _
    "<b>Column 1</b></td><td style=""width:10%"" nowrap><b>Column 2</b></td><td style=""width:10%"" nowrap><b>Column 3</b></td></tr>"

For Each r In r.Cells
    If r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204) Then
        m = m & "<tr><td>" & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & r) & "</td><td>" & ActiveSheet.Range("L" & r) & "</td><td>" & _
            ActiveSheet.Range("M" & r) & "</td></tr>"
    End If
Next

'Open Email
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olMail As Object
Dim name As String

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With olMail
    .To = "Dee Wolf"
    .Subject = "This is a subject line"  
    .HTMLBody = m
    .Display
End With
Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You're testing for `A5:A500` but pulling data from columns D, L and M. Is that intentional? Edit: can you even do `Range("D" & r)` if `r` is a range? And you might want to change the second `r` to `c` for instance.

Comment: yes, change the 2nd `r` to `c` (or whatever letter) and then change `Range("D' & r)` to `Range("D" & c.Row)`

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I followed your direction correctly but I modified my code to the following, and it produces no results (where with my original code, it produces results, just not the correct results.)

Edit: Sorry, I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax of the message board system.

[For Each c In r.Cells]
[("D" & c.Row)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the r variable twice for 2 purposes, and why are you building a range using ("D" & r).  r is an object (specifically a cell). I am assuming you want to take data from D and M, but on the same row?

If so this should read as below.

Dim aCell as Range

```
For Each aCell In r.Cells
    If r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204) Then
        m = m & "<tr><td>" & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & aCell.Row) & "</td><td>" & ActiveSheet.Range("L" & aCell.Row) & "</td><td>" & _
            ActiveSheet.Range("M" & aCell.Row) & "</td></tr>"
    End If
Next
```

You may of course be taking a shortcut, and actually are using r.Value when you build a range using Range("D" & r).  i.e. this is shot for Range("D" & r.Value)...so if "r" references a cell with a number in it like 599, then you want to reference cell "D599" which is what your code does?

[image: This works for me]

Comment: Thanks Smackenzie. I am using range A5:A500 to determine the cell color. Then, once the specified cell color is found, I'm taking the data from that row's D, L, and M columns. I tried using your suggestion but the macro is no longer producing any results. It sounds like the method I'm using isn't quite normal but it also worked, it just wasn't giving me the correct results. So I'm more confused. lol.

Comment: to use Range("M" & r) can only give results if you are storing the row number in the cells with the colors in, and the code is then taking r.value?  Do you have the row numbers written in the cells A5:500.

Comment: It works!! Thank you @smackenzie I really appreciate the visual aid you provided.